# link area is either too small or obscures image in hidden div

Tags: css, image, hover, hyperlink, document.write

I have a menu bar at the top of my site. Clicking the "social" link shows a hidden div that contains a horizontal row of social icon images. I am now trying to get these images to link to the various sites and at wits' end.

If I just put a plain link around each image, the active/hover area is so small as to be useless. Maybe a couple pixels wide at the bottom of the image. If I try to style the link in css, the image disappears. The code I have now succeeds in making the active/hover area bigger but that hardly helps if you can no longer see the image.

I read some comments in other threads about negative margins messing this up and I do have one, but not in the same div. My CSS below is kind of sloppy/in progress but here's what I have at the moment (non-broken, reasonably useful link but no image--only with the final link at the moment).

```
/* MENU BLOCK */
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-color:#000;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
}

#logo {
    font-size:100px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    line-height:0px;
    font-weight:600;
}

#topNav {
    float:right;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    line-height:0px;
    margin-top:-65px;
    padding-right:5px;  
}

#topNav p {
    font-family:Cambria;
    font-size:24px;
}

#socialButtons {
    position:absolute;
    left:650px;
    top:32px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}

.socialButton {
    padding-top:5px;
    width:20px;
    margin-right:10px;  
}

.socialButton img {
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 50 !important;
    display: inline !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.socialLink {
    width:20px;
    height:2px;
    opacity:0;
    border:0;
    z-index:-5;
    background-color: white;
}

.socialLink a {
    opacity:0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

/* END MENU BLOCK */
```

And here is the menu I am working with (I know it's a doc.write file and that's probably bad, but I don't know any other way to do it so that it works the way I want it to.) I have only tried to link two of the images so far. FB has the tiny active area and IRC has a normal active area and no image.

```
document.write('<div id="menu"><h1 id="logo" class="brainFlower"><a href="/">Uppagus</a></h1><div id="topNav"><p><a href="http://uppagus.com/about">About</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://uppagus.com/archive">Archive</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="socialLink" href="">Social</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://uppagus.com/submit">Submit</a></p></div></div><div class="hiddenRow" id="socialButtons"><div id="socialContainer"><div class="socialNavi" style="top:-100px; left:690px;font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:#FFA200;">&darr;</div><div id="socialInfoi"></div></div><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Uppagus/182341685267191" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img class="socialButton" src="http://www.uppagus.com/img/fb.png" /></a><img class="socialButton" src="http://www.uppagus.com/img/twt.png" /><img class="socialButton" src="http://www.uppagus.com/img/g+.png" /><img class="socialButton" src="http://www.uppagus.com/img/rss.png" /><a class="socialLink" href="http://uppagus.com/irc/" title="IRC"><img class="socialButton" src="http://www.uppagus.com/img/irc.png" /></a></div>');
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say this, but this CSS and HTML is really messy and non-consistent.
From what I understood your only problem is that IRC image is not shown,
the only reason for that is that "**.socialLink**" class has "**opacity: 0**".
Regarding anchors not wrapping around its content in this case image,
you should put in

```
    display: block;
```

Comment: No need to be sorry; I know. Your advice worked well except now that image is pushed to a new "row" below the others. I suppose that is a different issue though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another div partially covering your link. I had the same issue. It took me a while to fix it, because it was hard to find the div that was interfering with the one containing the link. I added background colors to each nearby div until I found it. I also removed each nearby div one at a time, then checked if my link worked properly.

Also contributing to the problem was the use of e.g.

```
<div style="position:relative; top:-20px">
```

or

```
<div style="margin-top:-20px">
```

or using a css with the same directives applied to a div to position it. For example, if your div is:

```
<div id="mydiv">
```

and your css has:

```
#mydiv { position:relative; top:-20px; } or #mydiv { margin-top:-20px; }
```

This is how two divs can overlap in the first place. The same issue can occur with a form field - where you find you are not able to click in the field and insert the cursor.